# PHP - Creating Client for Java WSDL

Tags: java, php, web-services

I have ganerate a Web Service in Java using NetBeans.
The Web Service work succesfully when I consume it from Java too.
I want to consume it from PHP, how can I do that?

NewWebService.java

```
package NewWeb;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService {

@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
     public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
         return "Hello " + txt + " !";
     }
}
```

Client.java

```
package client;

public class Client {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // TODO code application logic here
         System.out.println(hello("Name"));
     }

     private static String hello(java.lang.String name) {
         newweb.NewWebService_Service service = new 
         newweb.NewWebService_Service();
         newweb.NewWebService port = service.getNewWebServicePort();
         return port.hello(name);
     }

}
```

Comment: In php `@WebMethod` is `$_GET` or `$_POST`. You should show some attempt in php so that we can help.

Comment: I have no idea about the PHP file. I don't know how can I start with it

Comment: In which case you should [do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and come back to StackOverflow when you get stuck on something specific.

Comment: I was looking from several sites.
Like here : http://java2db.com/web-services/how-to-call-java-soap-web-service-in-php
But it doesn't work